# Jquery append limit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example :

```
$("#good").append("third command <br>");
$("#good").append("secont command <br>");
$("#good").append("first command <br>");
```

If ı append fourth command ı wanna delete firs command and add new command:

```
$("#good").append("fourth command <br>");
$("#good").append("third command <br>");
$("#good").append("secont command <br>");
//first append deleted
```

how can i make this ?

Comment: Suppose you just keep text like "first command" in an array, and always just `$("#good").html(array.join("<br>"))`.  Then always `array.shift()` the first element, then `array.push()` the new element.  Working with the arrays will be much easier than parsing/counting the DOM elements.

Comment: can you make a example on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Or why not use a list `<ul>`, `<li>` instead of line breaks? You'd have an easier time manipulating the nodes that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method using my array approach mentioned in the comment:

http://jsfiddle.net/p5UW7/1/

```
var myarray = [];
var current = 1;

$('#theButton').click(function() {
    if (myarray.length >= 3) {
        myarray.shift(); //remove the first entry
    }
    myarray.push("item " + current++); //push the new entry onto the array
    $('#container').html(myarray.join("<br>")); //set the markup using the new array
});
```

FYI, if you want to present items in reverse order, this jsfiddle uses `pop()` and `unshift()` in the same fashion

http://jsfiddle.net/p5UW7/2/

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change your markup a little for this solution, but it appears to work well. You can use `:lt()` to find items with an index less than the specified index. Using a negative number starts counting from the end. So `:lt(-4)` selects all but the last 4 elements. Here's a demo you can tailor to your own use:

http://jsfiddle.net/p5UW7/

```
<button id="theButton">Add item</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

---

```
var current = 1;
$('#theButton').click(function() {
   $('#container').append('<div>item ' + current++ + '</div>');
    $('#container div:lt(-4)').remove();
});
```

Comment: Hm.. after reading your question again, I'm not sure this is what you were looking for.. let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should append the content into an html element, I'd suggest a "div".
On event that triggers the append occurs (lets say that its a button click), you can do...

```
$("btn").on('click',function(){
                    $("#good").append("<span>command</span>");
                    if($("#good").length>3){
                        $("#good append")[0].remove();
                    }
                });
```

PS: Use CSS to break lines instead of multiples `<br>`

Comment: I believe the line that removes the child should be `$("#good span")[0].remove()`?

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a helper plugin for this job:

```
$.fn.limitAppend = function (limit, content) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).children().filter(':lt(-' + (limit - 1) + ')').remove();
        $('<div>').append(content).appendTo(this);
    });
};
```

And use it instead of `append`:

```
$("#good").limitAppend(3, "1st command");
$("#good").limitAppend(3, "2nd command");
$("#good").limitAppend(3, "3rd command");
$("#good").limitAppend(3, "4th command");
$("#good").limitAppend(3, "5th command");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/637K3/1/